# PFSense on AWS with ASG

Tags: pfsense, aws

Have any of you had any experience using PFSense and Auto Scaling in AWS?

Does PFSense have support for a user-data field? [1]

Is there a way of running start-up custom scripts inside PFSense?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on replacing a bunch of sophos firewalls with pfSense ones. My first impression is that pfSense isn't yet ready to the cloud. As a cloud user, you would expect that you could automate every aspect of your infrastructure and pfSense doesn't help with this.

You can't use userdata to script the instance startup and it lacks ASG integration as well. Also, the configuration is expected to be generated by its GUI only.

We managed to automate the instance creation and config.xml generation using ansible ( essentially using a template to generate the XML file ) so this is an advantage compared to Sophos.

I believe it would be possible (and probably easy) to extend pfSense and add support to autoscaling groups in there - as an external package or plugin or whatever they call it ( that's actually a good idea of a pet project )

Comment: I agree with you in the sentence "pfSense isn't yet ready to the cloud"; however, s not easy to add it support for autoscaling and userdata.

It will require to add cloud-init to pfSense, and other tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked two separate questions. (*three questions, but anyone answering should be assumed to be inherently answering the first question*).

1. There are very few use cases for autoscaling a firewall where the
   autoscaling itself won't break the firewall's functionality, so it
   seriously depends on the use case itself (and the particular firewall's capabilities). Things like dynamic
   routing protocols, tunneling, and other functionality inside
   firewall vendor implementations don't expect the device to be
   autoscaled into multiple cloned devices all trying to accomplish the
   same single task.

   It's not that it's not possible or desirable to have autoscaling
   firewalls in AWS, in fact Juniper SRX's have a whole KB guide on
   autoscaling (for securing load-balancing traffic)... but again, the use-case is specific and limited.

   This is in contrast to having two separate firewalls in a
   high-availability configuration, something that every single
   firewall vendor has designed their gear to operate in, something the
   configuration and operation of the firewall can expect.
2. Your second question related to startup scripts- yes, any
   ec2-instance can have  start-up script information added at
   provisioning-time, but whether the pfsense product is designed to
   accept such scripting is not likely unless it was designed to do so
   in a traditional physical environment as well, and then it would
   have to accept it at the time AWS inserts it in it's provisioning
   process... which is to say, not likely.

   You may be forced to go this route, but if not, then instead of trying to figure out the exact method to accomplish this in the AWS environment, it might be more efficient and forward-thinking to have any scripting to customize a freshly-provisioned firewall be done after the instance is provisioned, or done ahead of time in a stored AMI that can be used
   in a template fashion if this isn't the last time you expect to
   provision a like firewall.